# How to use more/less black textcolor in function of the value of numbers in a table?

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional

A few weeks ago, I viewed in the Mathematica Documentation any page withmultiple examples using diferent styles dpending on the value of the number in position (i,j), but I can´t remember... and I can´t find it.

How can I use BLACK color to Print numbers that are close to the maximun?  and much light gray as much close it is to the minimum ?

```
a = {1, 3, 6, 3, 2};
b = {3, 2, 5, 6, 9};
c = {2, 7, 3, 1, 6};
TableForm[{a, b, c}]
```

In this case, 1,2,3 appear with light gray, and 9 with BLACK!!!

I remember... in that page there was many examples.

Can you help me?

Comment: Similar as in  Öskå's ecample,  `style[list_] := Module[{st, max},
  max = Max[list];
  
  st = Style[#, GrayLevel[1 - #/max]] &;
  Return[st /@ list]
  ]`

Comment: Thank You!! I can´t view any result. I´m learning. But... in the future I went back to view again :-).  I remeber that in those pages there are multiple examples in Dcoumentation, but I can´t remember how to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once again, it is in the documentation so it's probably going to be closed. But here you go:

```
makeGray = Text[Style[#, GrayLevel@(1 - #/10)]] &;
a = {1, 3, 6, 3, 2};
b = {3, 2, 5, 6, 9};
c = {2, 7, 3, 1, 6};
makeGray /@ # & /@ {a, b, c} // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you I know that this is too easy for many of you, but... I´m learning and starting.